# Sort tuples alphabetically

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying sort a list of tuples of bigrams alphabetically with python. My output now looks like this:

```
('hello', 'how')
('how', 'are')
('are', 'you')
('you', '?')
('Are', 'you')
('you', 'okay')
('okay', '?')
```

I want the output to look like this, ordered alphabetically and with only one occurrence of each bigram, preferably with a frequency count:

```
('are', 'you'), 2
('hello', 'how'), 1
('how', 'are'), 1
('okay', '?'), 1
('you', 'okay'), 1
('you', '?'), 1
```

My code looks like this:

```
def bigram(x):
    with open (x, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        mylist = f.read()
        n = 2
        grams = ngrams(nltk.word_tokenize(mylist), n)
        for bigrams in grams:
            return bigrams
```

I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: To sort your tuples, use sorted with a key: `sorted(list_of_tuples, key = lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: Is there a special reason why you expect `('you', 'okay')` to be printed before the `('you', '?')`?  That's not according to ASCII code.

Comment: @Alfe perhaps its alphabetic on first element and reverse alphabetical on second?

Comment: @NickA Yes, that will be it.  How could I miss that?

Answer (score 2):

At the first, you must make all data to lower case :

```
L = [('hello', 'how'), ('how', 'are'), ('are', 'you') ,('you', '?'), ('Are', 'you') ,('you', 'okay') ,('okay', '?')]
L = [tuple(s.lower() for s in x) for x in L]
```

Then count frequency:

```
import collections
counter=collections.Counter(L)
```

and then you can sort this:

```
print(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(counter.items())))
#OrderedDict([(('are', 'you'), 2), (('hello', 'how'), 1), (('how', 'are'), 1), (('okay', '?'), 1), (('you', '?'), 1), (('you', 'okay'), 1)])
```

Comment: Why do you use the `lower_if_possible()` instead of `lower()` directly?  Do you expect any input which isn't lowerable, e. g. some non-strings?  Where should they come from?

Comment: @Alfe for some case like ('old', 30)

Comment: But given the code of the OP this input should never occur.  `word_tokenize()` should return a list of strings, and `ngram()` should group the elements of this list.  Where should the `30` come from?

Comment: Thanks, It's my mistake. I changed it

Comment: No problem :)  Now you arrived at essentially my answer ;-)  ⁺¹ for this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do several steps (after reading the `grams`):

First, lowercase everything to ease finding doubles:

```
grams = [ (a.lower(), b.lower()) for (a, b) in grams ]
```

Second, group the `grams` and count them:

```
import collections
counted = collections.Counter(grams)
```

Third, sort the counted stuff:

```
for gram, count in sorted(counted.items()):
    print gram, count
```

Comment: Yes, +1, or in one line `sorted(collections.Counter((a.lower(),b.lower()) for a,b in grams).items())`

Comment: @Alfe Thanks! This works when I split the list, but not when I'm using nltk.word(tokenize) to tokenize the list... I get an error message:

  File "/Users/sohe/Desktop/bigram.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    grams = [(a.lower(), b.lower()) for (a,b) in grams]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). 

Do you have any idea what caused this=

Comment: That's caused by having a tuple of the wrong size in the list (I don't know how it got there).  You can lowercase tuples of arbitrary size by using this kind of code: `grams = [ tuple(q.lower() for q in gram) for gram in grams ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). Use the counter to count the number of occurances of each bigram and use sorted to sort the bigrams and corresponding countd alphabetically.